# Mongodb aggregate project string as number

Tags: string, mongodb, numbers

I have a mongo script which retrieves a value from an array and creates a new document. However, the value which it retrieves is a string. I need the value to be added to the new document as a number instead of a string because it is read by a graphing engine which ignores the value if it is a string.

From the script below, it is **"value": {$arrayElemAt: ["$accountBalances", 1]}** which needs to be a number instead of a string. Thanks.

```
 db.std_sourceBusinessData.aggregate(
{ $match : {objectType: "Account Balances"}},
{ $project: {_id: 1,entity_ID: 1,objectOrigin: 1,accountBalances: 1}},
{ $unwind: "$accountBalances" },
{ $match: {"accountBalances": "Sales"}}
,
{$project: {
_id: 1
, "value": {$arrayElemAt: ["$accountBalances", 1]}
,"key": {$literal: "sales"}
  ,"company": "$entity_ID"
,"objectOrigin" : "$objectOrigin"
}}
,{$out: "entity_datapoints"}
)
```

This is what I currently get:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5670961f910e1f54662c1d9d"),
"objectOrigin" : "Xero",
"Value" : "500.00",
"key" : "grossprofit",
"company" : "e56e09ef-5c7c-423e-b699-21469bd2ea00"
}
```

what I want is:

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("5670961f910e1f54662c1d9d"),
"objectOrigin" : "Xero",
"Value" : 500.0000000000000,
"key" : "grossprofit",
"company" : "e56e09ef-5c7c-423e-b699-21469bd2ea00"
}
```

Comment: That would require type casting, which is not supported by MongoDB aggregations. you need to do the type casting either when saving the original data or when processing the returned data.

Comment: the original document that comes in is from a JSON which is a report so everything is a string, I then standardise it into a document where I will have the same problem. I create data points from it which feed into a dashboard which is what the above script does. So, are you saying that there is no way of scripting taking a value and inserting it into a field of number type? Thanks

Comment: You could unmarshal the JSON, do the type casting replacing the original value and save the object to MongoDB.